# Pipeline of WebServices(Springboot)

Tags: web-services, intellij-idea, spring-boot

As a part of asignment we need to create a spring boot web service.

This web service would call another web service.

So let us assume we have two web services 'A' and 'B'.
Here 'A' is the 'caller' and 'B' is the 'Callee'.

Dere is a client program(any normal Java program) that would call web service 'A' 
which in turn would call web service 'B'.

The web service 'B' would have some business logic.
Hence we are creating a pipeling of web services.

I use IntelliJIDEA as IDE.

I need is a sample example which I could refer and start with it.
If possible just suggest any links.

Also I would like to know whether I need to create 'A' and 'B' as separate spring boot projects?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this home work? What have you tried so far? Or are you expecting someone to do the assignment for you?

Comment: @onnoweb Thanks for spending time to read my question.You have raised 3 questions.I think probably because you might not have read my question completely.This is an assignment.I have asked for any sample examples or any websites where I could find something that could probably answer my question.I do not expect anyone to completely develop the prototype.I think that would answer Question 1 & 3.I have created a sample service using spring boot for CRUD operations.Hence 'A' is available.I have the logic for 'B'. I am just stuck with calling 'B' from 'A'.I hope this might give you a clear picture

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) as a method to call the other service. There are other ways to call the second service, of course, but this way is already built into spring, so you don't have extra dependencies.